# test location provider in android instrumentation test project

Tags: android, unit-testing, location

I have an application, which uses the LocationManager. Therefore I'm now writing an instrumentation test. I've found already a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972895/testing-gps-in-android/3940877#3940877), but this won't work for me.

```
public class LocationSensorTest extends AndroidTestCase {
  /*package*/ LocationManager lm;
  private LocationSensor sensor;

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    sensor = new LocationSensor(getContext());
    lm = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.addTestProvider("test", false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled("test", true);
  }

  public void testHasAnyActiveLocationProvider() {
    assertTrue(sensor.hasAnyActiveLocationProvider());
  }
}
```

The test fails during the "addTestProvider" with a SecurityException that the "android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" is missing. The Point is that the instrumentation test AndroidManifest.xml has this uses permission, but the application to test not.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="de.app.android.tests" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application>
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  </application>
  <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" android:targetPackage="de.app.android" android:label="Requester App Tests" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
</manifest>
```

Has somebody an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

should be outside of `<application></application>`

Comment: that is unfortunately not the solution, because the real application has not the permission.. :(

Comment: But it needs it to be tested like this. And it also needs to be outside of the <application> tags in any case.