# Android requestLocationUpdates without minDistance

Tags: java, android, gps, location, locationmanager

I have a need to get the gps location every 20 seconds or so, but ignoring the need to have the user move a certain number of meters, I tried setting the minDistance to zero but still no luck, its only when I manually send the location using the location control from DDMS that this gets activated and the location gets updated.

Note - This is run and tested from the emulator and not a real device, for now at least

```
private final static Long INTERVAL_TIME = new Long(20);
private final static Float METERS_MOVED_VALUE = 0f;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.journey);

    Bundle dataBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    try {
        driverData = new JSONObject(dataBundle.getString("driverData"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Set the UI elements into variables
    journeyDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.journeyDescription);
    journeyText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.journeyText);
    confirmButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);

    //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            try{
                //Until requests are found keep broadcasting the drivers location and checking for requests
                if(!foundRequest){
                    updateDriverLocationAndCheckForNewDriverRequests(location);
                }

                //Always keep updating the drivers location
                Double latitude = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
                Double longitude = location.getLongitude()*1E6;
                geoPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude.intValue(), longitude.intValue());

            }catch(JSONException e){
                Toast.makeText(JourneyActivity.this, "An unexpected error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    //Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates can be either gps provider
    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){  
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, INTERVAL_TIME, METERS_MOVED_VALUE, locationListener);
    }
    else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, INTERVAL_TIME, METERS_MOVED_VALUE, locationListener);
    }
}
```

Here is the related code fragment, any ideas on how to trigger the listener without having the user move or me having to send information from the DDMS Location Controls woild be greatly appreciated

Regards,
Milinda

Comment: I would suggest to create a own thread or service, which requested every 20 seconds the last fix

Comment: I am new to android so pardon my ignorance if any, but even if a thread is used won't the LocationListener still require a certain min time interval be met and a certain min distance be moved?

Comment: are you outside? The gps only works well on a device with clear sky.
the network provided coordinates are only accurate *i think* to 100 m.

Comment: This is running on the emulator actually, I haven't got hold of a device yet to test. The networked co-ordinates are only a backup if the users phone does not support GPS, however the prototype will have GPS so that wont be an issue either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

requestLocationUpdates takes milliseconds, not seconds.
You should change:

```
private final static Long INTERVAL_TIME = new Long(20);
private final static Float METERS_MOVED_VALUE = 0f;
```

to:

```
private final static int INTERVAL_TIME_SECONDS = 20 * 1000; // 20 seconds
private final static float INTERVAL_DISTANCE_METERS = 0f; // 0 meters
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as testing on the emulator goes. I think your limited to manually pushing GPS locations or creating a few automated simulators:
[Testing GPS in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972895/testing-gps-in-android)