# setTestProviderLocation() does not trigger calling of onLocationChanged()

Tags: android, junit, locationmanager

I'm trying to get this bit of code to work:

[Testing GPS in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972895/testing-gps-in-android/3940877#3940877)

The problem is, when I run the test, onLocationChanged() is never called:

```
public class LocationTest0 extends AndroidTestCase implements LocationListener {
private Location received = null;
public void testExample() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String testProvider = "Test";

    if (null == lm.getProvider(testProvider)){
        lm.addTestProvider(testProvider, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    }

    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(testProvider, true);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(testProvider, 0, 0, this);
    lm.setTestProviderStatus(testProvider, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());

    Location location = new Location(testProvider);
    location.setLatitude(1.0);
    location.setLongitude(2.0);
    location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    lm.setTestProviderLocation(testProvider, location);

    Assert.assertFalse("Received Location is null", received == null );

    lm.removeTestProvider(testProvider);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    received = location;
    Log.d("LocationTest0", "onLocationChanged CALLED");
    // Never gets called
}
```

Comment: do you put all the permissions to the manifest?

Comment: Yes George, it's there - I know it's ok because it threw up an error for the permission before which I'd corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what worked for me

```
locationManager.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider, false, false,
                    false, false, true, true, true, 0, 5);
locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);
```

.

```
Location mockLocation = new Location(mocLocationProvider); // a string
mockLocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());  // double 
mockLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude()); 
mockLocation.setAltitude(location.getAltitude()); 
mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
locationManager.setTestProviderLocation( mocLocationProvider, mockLocation);
```

.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION">
```

Also in the android phone settings make sure you have the "Allow mock locations" checkbox ticked

Comment: Your code seems to just do the same thing? I'm using the emulator, but it has Allow Mock Locations checked.

Comment: I added setTime and setAltitude to the locations, still no calls to onLocationChanged().

Comment: If the code is the same as mine then it probably is the emulators fault. I rarely work with emulators when it comes to GPS.

Comment: Thanks again - sadly no luck, I'm getting the same problem testing on a real device. onLocationChanged() just doesn't want to get called

Comment: Weird. What is the name of your mock location provider?

Comment: I've used "Test" as the name for the mock location provider

Comment: I've used LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER as mock name. I've no idea why I did it though. I know its wrong and stuff. Can you try it once? :)

Comment: When I do that, it tells me to add the permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. And when I do that, IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown, caused by `lm.setTestProviderEnabled(testProvider, true);`

Comment: Although that new error is a problem with the conditional I use, which stops the testProvider "gps" being created. if I remove the conditional, it gets created but the old problem comes back, onLocationChanged is never called

Comment: Say, can this be used to mock the location to other apps? I've noticed we have an option to choose which app will be allowed to mock the location in the developer options... Is this what some mocking apps do? Also, is it possible to use special commands that are available only for rooted devices?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and could get it to work. I'll share it here in case it can help anyone else.

The thing to consider is that any call to `setTestProviderLocation` will invoke any listener registered on the mock providers at the time of the invocation. So if you call `setTestProviderLocation` and right after that call `requestLocationUpdates`, the `onLocationChanged` callback never gets called.

My problem was that I had these two (`setTestProviderLocation` and `requestLocationUpdates`) in two different threads and `requestLocationUpdates` was called after, so I never got a callback to `onLocationChanged`. If your program is multi-threaded (which very likely is) make sure `setTestProviderLocation` is called after `requestLocationUpdates`.

Also I noticed for any call to `setTestProviderLocation`, `onLocationChanged` will be called once (approximately). So you can put `setTestProviderLocation` in a loop to simulate a series of calls to `onLocationChanged`. This way you can simulate a path as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Couldn't resolve it and finally I gave up and added a call to `onLocationChanged( location)` after `locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled( PROVIDER, location)` manually. It's not pretty but works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.  Regardless of what I tried, I could never get onLocationChanged() to be automatically called.  Eventually, I gave up and created a method that both set the location with setTestProviderLocation() and directly called onLocationChanged().  It's not a perfect solution, but it worked for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

After adding and enabling your Provider just use this line to get the updates :
`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(MOCK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);`

I recommend to use a method like this on activity start-up :

```java
    private void enableProvider() {
        
        try {
            locationManager.addTestProvider(
                    MOCK_PROVIDER,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    0,
                    5
            );
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "addTestProvider" + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(MOCK_PROVIDER, true);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(MOCK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this); <-- Update Request
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "setTestProviderEnabled" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Handle the exceptions as well.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with this issue, I think the problem is TestProvider, so I set

`String mocLocationProvider= LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;`

and then it can call `onLocationChanged()`.