# I can't receive locations

Tags: java, android, location

I'm building a location based app, everything was fine until one day I stopped receiving locations.. I have no idea why. I will attach the important code:

```
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
    ...
    // Get a reference to the LocationManager object.
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ...
    setup();
}
private void setup() 
{
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listener);

    // Request updates from just the providers.
    if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) 
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, ONE_MINUTE, 0, listener);

    if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) 
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, ONE_MINUTE, 0, listener);
}


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        handleLocation(location);
    }
```

I put a break point on the onLocationChanged and nothing happened.. I tested it on other lines of my app to make sure that the debugging configuration is working and it is working. Looks like I just don't receive any locations.

Maybe I'm not seeing something.

Comment: Are you running on a device or emulator?

Comment: On my device, SAMSUNG GALAXY S3. It used to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015172/settestproviderlocation-does-not-trigger-calling-of-onlocationchanged How are you testing? This link might help.

Comment: I heared about this way of testing but if I put a breakpoint on the onLocationChanged method or on the handleLocation method or inside the handleLocation method it should trigger when location obtained and I'm sure because it used to! and now nothing! maybe because it's cloudy? I can't find a reason

Answer (score 0):

I've good code to receive location :

```
public class Locato extends Activity implements LocationListener { 
  LocationManager locman; 
  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.idlayout); 
    locman = (LocatonManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
  } 

  public void onStatusChanged(String pr, int s, Bundle a) {
  } 

  @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
  { 
    Log.d("MyApp", "Provider disabled : " + provider); 
  }
  @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("MyApp", "Provider enabled : " + provider);
  } 
  @Override public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
// do something 
  }
}
```

Try to use this. 
Don't forget add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in manifest.

Comment: I can't see the difference, you just implemented the LocationListener class instead of make an instance.

Answer (score 0):

The same code now generates locations, it was kind of a joke when I said that it could be since it's cloudy but now when the clouds are gone it's working. I can't think about anything else and just to clarify it was very cloudy maybe even a small storm.